# How can I prove that: $\lim_{n→+∞}(S_n - S_{n-1})=0?$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to prove on my own that

$$\lim_{n→+∞}U_n=0$$

is a necessary condition for the convergence of the numerical series of general term $U_n$.

I achieved the step of:

$$\lim_{n→+∞}(S_n - S_{n-1})=\lim_{n→+∞}U_n,$$

but I didn't know how to continue.
In my text book, I saw that the last step is just putting the limit equal to $0$ and thus $\lim_{n→+∞}U_n$.

But I don't get it why the limit of difference is null?
And if it is, why we can't apply the same reasoning with other terms for example $S_{n-2}$ instead of $S_{n-1}$?

Comment: if $S_n -2$ was used with $S_n-1$, then you would be equating $U_n-1$, which is not what you are trying to prove.

Comment: What is $S_n$, what is $U_n$ and are they related in any way?

Answer (score 2):

If $\lim x_n=x$ and $\lim y_n=y$ then $\lim(x_n-y_n)=x-y.$ Apply this to $x_n=S_n$ and $y_n=S_{n-1}.$

Comment: Thank you, but what I don't release is why the limit of difference is null?

Comment: In our example, $x=y=$ the sum of the series. More generally, if $\lim x_n=x$ then $\lim x_{n-1}=x.$

Comment: So I can say that the limit of the difference between two sequencive terms of a numerical convergent serie equal to 0 when n become big enough aka n→+∞

Comment: Indeed, for the reason indicated in my previous comment. (But I don't know the word "sequencive". I know "consecutive".)